Transaction History CGW API return 404 "An error occurred"
Describe the Bug
I've deployed safe with safe-infrastructure repo for Viction chain, then I successfully created the transaction transferring VIC from a safe to another safe through Safe UI. (https://www.vicscan.xyz/tx/0x34c9bc1203b246f62dfb50fd783bfafdbb15f3bdab0d65254f9c96510c5878d8)
But then the transaction history api returned 404
/cgw/v1/chains/88/safes/0x2a02e3e60ce7409e1e357eda0eb01bbd661d2a23/transactions/history
{
    "code": 404,
    "message": "An error occurred"
}

Here are the logs from cgw-web
cgw-web-1  | {"build_number":"85e2d8b","level":"info","message":{"chain_id":"88","client_ip":"172.71.124.48","detail":"An error occurred","method":"GET","origin":null,"path":"/v1/chains/88/safes/0x2a02e3e60ce7409e1e357eda0eb01bbd661d2a23/transactions/history","response_time_ms":2.3340130001306534,"route":"/v1/chains/:chainId/safes/:safeAddress/transactions/history","safe_app_user_agent":null,"status_code":404},"request_id":"58472692-af60-46c2-8674-490ede0aed3f","timestamp":"2024-11-04T09:13:18.915Z","version":"v1.60.1"}
cgw-web-1  | {"build_number":"85e2d8b","level":"info","message":{"chain_id":"88","client_ip":"172.71.124.48","detail":null,"method":"GET","origin":null,"path":"/v1/chains/88/safes/0x2a02e3e60ce7409e1e357eda0eb01bbd661d2a23/transactions/history","response_time_ms":3.487381999846548,"route":"/v1/chains/:chainId/safes/:safeAddress/transactions/history","safe_app_user_agent":null,"status_code":404},"request_id":"58472692-af60-46c2-8674-490ede0aed3f","timestamp":"2024-11-04T09:13:18.916Z","version":"v1.60.1"}

To Reproduce Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Setup using https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/
Create safe wallet UI
Go to dashboard -> transaction history

Expected behavior: It should display the transaction history
Environments:

Production
Chain: viction
Chrome
Version: latest on all components

REVERSE_PROXY_PORT=80

CFG_VERSION=latest
CGW_VERSION=latest
TXS_VERSION=latest
UI_VERSION=latest
EVENTS_VERSION=latest

RPC_NODE_URL=https://rpc.viction.xyz

Additional Context



I've found that the issue came from RPC and not the safe 
